# Pivot case when?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have the following data table:

```
id                                      displayName stringValue     dateValue
59FAA56C-4C0C-456E-BA68-AC63250D6281    User SID    SID-122         NULL
EBD6F18D-3CD3-4134-8FFB-7620D3EA93DF    User SID    SID2            NULL
59FAA56C-4C0C-456E-BA68-AC63250D6281    User Name   My User         NULL
EBD6F18D-3CD3-4134-8FFB-7620D3EA93DF    User Name   User 2          NULL
59FAA56C-4C0C-456E-BA68-AC63250D6281    Last Login  NULL            2012-01-01
EBD6F18D-3CD3-4134-8FFB-7620D3EA93DF    Last Login  NULL            2012-01-10
```

That I would like to turn into:

```
id                                      [User SID]  [User Name] [Last Login]
59FAA56C-4C0C-456E-BA68-AC63250D6281    SID-122     My User     2012-01-01
EBD6F18D-3CD3-4134-8FFB-7620D3EA93DF    SID2        User 2      2012-01-10
```

Which I can get to partially work by using the following pivot:

```
SELECT id, [User SID], [User Name], [Last Login] from 
            (
                select id
                    , stringValue
                    , displayName
                from #TestTable
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 MAX(stringValue)
                for displayName in ([User SID], [User Name], [Last Login])
            ) p
```

Except that lastLogin gets populated with NULL (which makes sense, because its not included in the MAX anywhere).

Now, I have tried to change the pivot to be:

```
            pivot 
            (
                 MAX(ISNULL(stringValue,dateValue))
                for displayName in ([User SID], [User Name], [Last Login])
            ) p
```

And also:

```
            pivot 
            (
                 MAX(CASE WHEN stringValue IS NULL THEN dateValue ELSE stringValue END)
                for displayName in ([User SID], [User Name], [Last Login])
            ) p
```

But neither of those are valid sql. Any suggestions on how I could get this to work properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you need to use `PIVOT`?, because a simple way for this would be to use `CASE` expressions:

```
SELECT  id,
        MIN(CASE WHEN displayName = 'User SID' THEN stringValue END) [User SID],
        MIN(CASE WHEN displayName = 'User Name' THEN stringValue END) [User Name],
        MIN(CASE WHEN displayName = 'Last Login' THEN dateValue END) [Last Login]
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY id
```

Here is the result:

```
╔══════════════════════════════════════╦══════════╦═══════════╦════════════╗
║                  ID                  ║ USER SID ║ USER NAME ║ LAST LOGIN ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════╬══════════╬═══════════╬════════════╣
║ EBD6F18D-3CD3-4134-8FFB-7620D3EA93DF ║ SID2     ║ User 2    ║ 2012-01-10 ║
║ 59FAA56C-4C0C-456E-BA68-AC63250D6281 ║ SID-122  ║ My User   ║ 2012-01-01 ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════╩══════════╩═══════════╩════════════╝
```

[**And here is a sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f9633/1) with a demo for you to try.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the values by unpivoting and then pivoting the data.  The unpivot process will convert the `stringValue` and `dateValue` columns into multiple rows and then you can PIVOT the `displayname` column values:

```
select id, [User SID], [User Name], [Last Login]
from
(
  select t.id,
    t.displayname,
    c.value
  from yourtable t
  cross apply
  (
    values
      ('stringvalue', stringvalue),
      ('datevalue', convert(varchar(10), datevalue, 120))
  ) c (col, value)
) src
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for displayname in ([User SID], [User Name], [Last Login])
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f9633/5).

The result is:

```
|                                   ID | USER SID | USER NAME | LAST LOGIN |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| EBD6F18D-3CD3-4134-8FFB-7620D3EA93DF |     SID2 |    User 2 | 2012-01-10 |
| 59FAA56C-4C0C-456E-BA68-AC63250D6281 |  SID-122 |   My User | 2012-01-01 |
```

Answer (score 2):

From the look of your data, unless you're also doing some calculations we haven't seen, you won't even need to use an aggregate function, much less a PIVOT.

I would do something like this:

```
 WITH UserSID
 AS (
    SELECT ID
        ,  [User SID] = stringValue
    FROM   [your table]
    WHERE  displayName = 'User SID'
 )
 ,  UserName
 AS (
    SELECT ID
       ,   [User Name] = stringValue
    FROM   [your table]
    WHERE  displayName = 'User name'
 )
 ,  LastLogin
 AS (
    SELECT ID
       ,   [Last Login] = dateValue
    FROM   [your table]
    WHERE  displayName = 'Last Login'
)
SELECT  us.ID
   ,    us.[User SID]  
   ,    un.[User Name]
   ,    ll.[Last Login]
FROM    UserSID us
    JOIN UserName un
       ON us.ID = un.ID
    JOIN LastLogin ll
       ON us.ID = ll.ID
ORDER BY
       us.ID
```

Comment: The problem comes when the query needs to return 5, or 12, or 33 values... PIVOT scales a lot nicer than a new scan, potentially, for every value.

Comment: @AaronBertrand True enough. My solution is only suitable for this specific, limited case.