# Pivoting data with CASE expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, aggregate-functions

I have the following query which gets the store, the week number and the sum of products sold :

```
select *
from 
(
  select store, week, xCount
  from yt
) src
pivot
(
  sum(xcount)
  for week in ([1], [2], [3])
) piv;
```

Is it possible to get the same result with CASE expression ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221373/pivot-case-when

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pivot with conditional aggregation as follows:

```
select 
    store, 
    sum(case when week = 1 then xcount else 0 end) week1,
    sum(case when week = 2 then xcount else 0 end) week2,
    sum(case when week = 3 then xcount else 0 end) week3
from yt
group by store
```

I tend to prefer conditional aggregation over database-specific `pivot` syntaxes:

- conditional aggregation is more flexible than `pivot`
- the syntax works across most databases, so it is much more portable
- performance is usually equivalent

Comment: how can you describe the flexibility ?

Comment: @mo-mhi: imagine that you want another column that sums values for week 2 and 3. With conditional aggregation, that's very easy to do with `sum(case when week in (2, 3) then xcount else 0 end) week2_and_week3`, whereas with `pivot` this will be much more complicated.